# Close a mobile web application running under Trigger.IO

Tags: trigger.io

What is the best practise for telling your application to close when hosting it with Trigger.IO?

I want a button on the front to exit the application... I heard that for Android `navigator.app.exitApp();` works, but got an error saying exitApp() didnt exit, but am hoping there is a more cross browser solution.

Comment: We've not implemented this - best practice seems to be to let the user quit the app with the back button, rather than duplicating that action inside apps

Comment: Yeah I didn't see anything on the docs. That is how im doing things at the moment, it would just be nice to give the user some way to *know* they have closed the application. As I am always going to the task manager and closing down apps that *should* have closed.

Comment: I would like to be able to quit the app with a command.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `forge.event.backPressed` to listen for back button presses, and optionally quit the app there. E.g.:

```
forge.event.backPressed.preventDefault(function () {
  forge.event.backPressed.addListener(function (closeMe) {
    closeMe(); // this closes the app
  });
});
```

Comment: Based on the docs https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/core/event.html this only works for Android.  Is there an equivalent for iOS?

Answer (score 0):

James posted the documented method of closing the app, but the internal method can also be called like this:

```
forge.internal.call('event.backPressed_closeApplication');
```

This method is confirmed to work on Android, unsure whether it will work on iOS.